# How to convert html text to mobi format

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to convert html to mobi. Does anyone know how to do that? I've figure out how to convert HTML to pdf, but kindle works better if the file format is mobi format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are online tools to convert html to mobi format: https://www.onlineconverter.com/html-to-mobi
A lot, better convertio: https://convertio.co/es/html-mobi/

Comment: @LouisaScheinost There is a API: https://cloudconvert.com/html-to-mobi https://cloudconvert.com/api/v2